# I want to stay on same text layer after using pen tool to created path

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, path

I have used the pen tool to create a path.  When I select the text tool and place it on the path, rather than setting a point to begin typing, a new text layer is created instead. What do I need to do to remain on the layer where I have set the path?

Comment: I don't believe you can do that, but, why do you want to remain on the same layer? Perhaps there is a way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you **are** on the same layer, but a new **object** is created when you click with text tool. Illustrator layers *are not* like Photoshop layers.

Illustrator's "Layers" Panel is actually a 'Layers & Objects' panel -- it shows you layers as well as the objects on those layers.

[image]

When you draw a path with the pen tool, you create a **path object**. When you click with the text tool, you create a **text object**. You aren't creating new layers.

In fact, I can't think of one instance where Illustrator *will* create a new Layer without the user *specifically* commands AI to. The user **must** ask AI to make a new layer.

There is *no way* to have different **objects** appear on the same "row" in the Layers Panel.

If you only want to *see* layers, you can change the Layer Panel Options and tick the "Show Layers Only" option.

[image]

This won't change how AI functions, but it will change what the Layers Panel shows you.